# How is this 2D matrix selection sort working out?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm asked a question to sort a 2D matrix using a selection sort. I got it to sort the 2D matrix but I just don't fully understand how it worked out or if I'm doing it in a efficient way or not.

```
const int ROWS = 3;
const int COLUMNS = 3;
void SelectionSort(int arr[ROWS][COLUMNS], int arrSize);

int main() {
    cout << "Enter values for the matrix" << endl;
    int arr[ROWS][COLUMNS];

    fill(arr);
    display(arr);
    
    //Compare if arr[0][0] with arr[0][1].
    //if arr[0][1] is larger than arr[0][0] , swap them.
    //Otherwise , keep comparing arr[0][n].

    cout <<"Sorted"<< endl;

    //Loops 9 times to fully sort the 2D matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        SelectionSort(arr, 9);
    }
    
    //Displays result
    display(arr);
    
    return 0;
}

void SelectionSort(int arr[ROWS][COLUMNS], int arrSize)
{
    // variable to store the index of the minimum value
    // in each iteration
    int minIndex;

    // Iterate until the N-1 elements
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize - 1; ++i)
    {
        // Set the first unsorted element
        // as the minimum value
        minIndex = i;

        // Iterate through the unsorted elements only
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arrSize; ++j)
        {
            // set the new minimum value
            // if the saved minimum value is higher
            // than the current index value
            if (arr[0][j] < arr[0][i]) // How is arr[0][j] working 
                minIndex = j;
        }

        // Swap the the first unsorted element
        // with the minimum value
        swap(arr[0][i], arr[0][minIndex]);
    }
}
```

I don't understand 2 parts.

A. When I call selection sort once , it only sorts the first row and the rest is unsorted. Only way ,that worked for me at least , is to call it 9 times. I imagined it to fully work on one call instead of 9.

B. From my understanding of 2D arrays in C++ , first square bracket is responsible for rows and the second one is for columns. In my case , I have arr [ 0 ] [ j ] and arr [ 0 ] [ i ] where j and i are being incrementing by 1 on each iteration. The way I see arr [ 0 ] [ j ] and arr [ 0 ] [ i ] is that I expected it not to work since the rows are always 0 , but somehow it did work out fine and it sorted the 2D matrix. How is this working out , my first attempt to this problem was putting a variable instead of a 0 in the first bracket where the variable would increment after 3 iterations.

Comment: Your sorting function will go out of bounds of the `arr[0]` array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It didn't . It worked fine.

Comment: "Working fine" is unfortunately one of the alternatives for *undefined behavior*. Think about it... `arr[0]` is an array of *three* elements. Yet you go through *nine* elements in it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand what you're saying . arr[0] is not being incremented anywhere in the code . Therefore , it will not go out of bounds as you claim. Had it been a variable , yes that's possible.

Comment: `arr[0]` is in turn an array, with elements `arr[0][0]`, `arr[0][1]` and `arr[0][2]`. Your code goes on to use `arr[0][4]` all the way to `arr[0][8]`.

Comment: ok so I didn't get any out of bounds error. I just dont understand how it managed to sort the matrix despite the fact I'm only using arr [ 0 ] [ j ] .

Comment: That's because of how arrays are laid out in memory. You have 3 times 3 (i.e. 9) elements laid out contiguously in memory. So your code appear to work. You still have undefined behavior since you go out of bounds (and remember that C++ have no bounds checking). Just don't do it. Pass a correct `arrSize` argument, or use the correct macro. Or better yet, use `std::array` and normal iterator.